Insertion operation bias in Grand Canonical Monte Carlo (GCMC) simulation software
I'm working on my own Grand Canonical Monte Carlo (GCMC) simulation software. The insertion operation, where an absorbate atom (e.g. hydrogen) is inserted in the system at a random position, is troublesome due to it's low acceptance ratio. To overcome it, most software uses some kind of bias to increase it:

From SCM-GCMC:


The Insert and Displace MC move will rotate the molecule randomly and
put it at a random position, and then check if the minimum interatomic
distance between the molecule and the rest of the system is within the
MinDistance and MaxDistance boundaries. If the condition is not
satisfied, a new set of coordinates is generated and the check is
performed again. This is repeated up to NumAttempts times before
stopping with an error.


From Lammps fix GCMC :


Insertion attempts occur only within the specified region. For
non-rectangular regions, random trial points are generated within the
rectangular bounding box until a point is found that lies inside the
region. If no valid point is generated after 1000 trials, no insertion
is performed, but it is counted as an attempted insertion.

Can somebody explain why/how to keep the detailed balance with these tweaked insertion operation ? By that, I mean if we have an insertion operation that is way more likely to succeed while keeping the same deletion operation, our system will incorrectly absorb more than it should.
My guess is that we need to redefine the probability of insertion ($P_{\text{ins}}$) by multiplying by a term proportional to the volume which is valid for insertion ($V_{\text{abs}}$):
$$P_{\text{ins}}^{\prime} = \left(\frac{V_{\text{abs}}}{V_{\text{tot}}}\right) P_{\text{ins}}.$$

I think have found the answer which is based on Chapter 4 and 9 of "Computer Simulation of Liquid" by Allen & Tidesley 2nd edition.
Definition :

$\alpha$ : Probability to do an operation
$\pi$ : One step transition probability matrix
$\rho$ : The probability to be in each state
Microscopic reversibility : Equivalent to detailed balance. Defined for a two state system as : $\rho_m \pi_{mn} = \rho_n
   \pi_{nm}$. In other words, the number of transition from m to n must be equal to the number of transition from n to m which is simply thermodynamic equilibrium.

Simple system summary :
A two state transition m and n where system in m has a 60% chance to stay in m and the system in n has a 70% chance to stay in n. We start with the initial state $\rho^{(1)} = (0.5, 0.5)$ :
$$\alpha_{mm} = 0.6;\hspace{5mm} \alpha_{mn} = 0.4;\hspace{5mm} \alpha_{nn}=0.7;\hspace{5mm} \alpha_{nm}=0.3$$
$$\mathbf{\pi} = \begin{pmatrix} 0.6 & 0.4 \\ 0.3 & 0.7 \end{pmatrix} ; \hspace{5mm} \rho^{(2)} = \rho^{(1)} \pi_{mn} ; 
\hspace{5mm} \lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty} \rho^{k} = (0.4286, 0.5714);
$$
And the detailed balance is :
$$
\hspace{5mm} (0.4286)(0.4) = (0.5714)(0.3);
$$
Key insight :
If we have an operation and its reverse counterpart, we can give both operation an equal probability. For a Markov Chain, this would be :
$$ \begin{split}
\pi_{mn} = \alpha_{mn}  \hspace{20mm}  &\rho_n \geq \rho_m\\ 
\pi_{mn} = \alpha_{mn} (\rho_n / \rho_m) \hspace{10mm} &\rho_n < \rho_m
\end{split}$$
If the operation are not reversible, we can keep the microscopic reversibility by redefining the link between $\alpha$ and $\pi$ like :
$$ \begin{split}
\pi_{mn} = \alpha_{mn}  \hspace{20mm}  & \alpha_{nm} \rho_n \geq \alpha_{mn} \rho_m\\ 
\pi_{mn} = \alpha_{mn} \left(\frac{\alpha_{nm} \rho_n}{\alpha_{mn} \rho_m}\right) \hspace{10mm} &\alpha_{nm} \rho_n < \alpha_{mn} \rho_m
\end{split}$$
GCMC case :
Now let's look at a Grand Canonical Monte Carlo simulation with only two operation : insertion and deletion. As in most GCMC package, we will use Markov Chain and probability based on Boltzmann factor on the grand potential difference :
Suppose we have an operation which corresponds to the insertion at a random position in the cell $\alpha_{\text{ins}}$ and which corresponds to deletion of a random absorbate atom $\alpha_{\text{del}}$. The operation are reversible and equiprobable. $n$ correspond to the site before insertion and $n+1$ to the system after the insertion.
$$\frac{\rho_i}{\rho_k} = \exp(-\beta \Delta \Phi)$$
$$ \begin{split}
\pi_{\text{ins}} = \alpha_{\text{ins}}  \hspace{20mm}  &\Phi_{n+1} \leq \Phi_n\\ 
\pi_{\text{ins}} = \alpha_{\text{ins}} \exp(-\beta \Delta \Phi) \hspace{10mm} &\Phi_{n+1} > \Phi_n
\end{split}$$
Now suppose we redefine the insertion operation to only try position inside a predefined absorption site $\alpha_{\text{ins}}^\prime$ and consider that every insertion outside an absorption site is automatically rejected. Then :
$$\begin{split}
\alpha_{n,n+1} = \alpha_{\text{ins}}^\prime \\
\alpha_{n+1,n} = \alpha_{\text{del}} = \alpha_{\text{ins}}
\end{split}
$$
$$\begin{split}
\pi_{\text{ins}} = \alpha_{\text{ins}}^\prime  \hspace{20mm}  & \alpha_{\text{ins}} \rho_{n+1} \geq \alpha_{\text{ins}}^\prime \rho_n\\ 
\pi_{\text{ins}} = \alpha_{\text{ins}}^\prime \left(\frac{\alpha_{\text{ins}}}{\alpha_{\text{ins}}^\prime}\right) \left(\frac{\rho_{n+1}}{\rho_n}\right) \hspace{10mm} &\alpha_{\text{ins}} \rho_{n+1} < \alpha_{\text{ins}}^\prime \rho_n
\end{split}$$
Finally, we realise that this new operation is equivalent to simply redefining the probability $$\frac{\rho_{n+1}}{\rho_{n}} \rightarrow \frac{V_{\text{abs}}}{V_{\text{tot}}} \frac{\rho_{n+1}}{\rho_{n}}$$.
To conclude, the software only has to try the new add operation less often, by a factor $\frac{V_{\text{abs}}}{V_{\text{tot}}}$. This should give the same result as with the first operation, but significantly faster
Note : Microscopic reversibility can be generalized to system with more states by making sure all pair of two respect microscopic reversibility.
